# Multicolumn alignment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, multicolumn

I am writing an article, but I have a problem when I write this table

```
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \caption{atomic composition of the different points analyzed by the DES probe}
    \label{DES probe}
    \begin{tabular}{
                c
                *{13}S[table-format=2.1]
            }
            \toprule
            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries{Weight\%}}\\
            \cmidrule(lr){2-14}
            {\bfseries{Point}} & {\boldmath{C}}    & {\boldmath{O}}    & 
            {\boldmath{Mg}}    & {\boldmath{Al}}    & {\boldmath{Si}}    & {\boldmath{S}}     & {\boldmath{K}}     & {\boldmath{Ca}} & {\boldmath{Ti}} & {\boldmath{Fe}} & {\boldmath{Zn}} & {\boldmath{Cu}} & {\boldmath{Pd}}  \\
            \midrule

            A & 0.0 & 50.5 & 1.6 & 7.4 & 24.3 & 7.9 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 6.2 & 0.6 & 0.0 & 1.5 \\

            B & 32.1 & 46.2 & 0.2 & 1.9 & 5.9 & 1.9 & 0.7 & 0.7 & 0.3 & 9.6 & 0.0 & 0.5 & 0.0\\

            C & 0.0 & 43.0 & 0.0 & 3.6 & 10.8 & 6.7 & 1.1 & 3.2 & 0.4 & 31.1 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
            \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

The title "weight %" don't appear centered in the multicolumn arrangement.

Could anybody help me to fix it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: welcome to tex.se! please. extend your table code to small, but complete document beginning with `\documentclass{...} and ending with `\end{document}`. help us to help you!

Comment: if you like to have "weight" on the middle of columns with numbers, than you should write:  `\multicolumn{13}{c}{\bfseries{Weight (\%)}}\\`

Comment: `{\boldmath{C}}` is the same as `C` as `\boldmath` is a declaration that makes any later math be bold but there is no math in the scope of the cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let me elaborate my comment above:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[skip=1ex, labelfont=bf]{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
\caption{atomic composition of the different points analyzed by the DES probe}
\label{DES probe}
\begin{tabular}{@{} c
           *{13}S[table-format=2.1]
                @{} }
    \toprule
        & \multicolumn{13}{c}{\thead{Weight (\%)}}      \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-14}
\thead{Point}   & {\thead{C}}   & {\thead{O}}   & {\thead{Mg}}    
                & {\thead{Al}}  & {\thead{Si}}  & {\thead{S}}   
                & {\thead{K}}   & {\thead{Ca}}  & {\thead{Ti}} 
                & {\thead{Fe}}  & {\thead{Zn}}  & {\thead{Cu}} 
                & {\thead{Pd}}                          \\
    \midrule
A & 0.0  & 50.5 & 1.6 & 7.4 & 24.3 & 7.9 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 &  6.2 & 0.6 & 0.0 & 1.5\\
B & 32.1 & 46.2 & 0.2 & 1.9 &  5.9 & 1.9 & 0.7 & 0.7 & 0.3 &  9.6 & 0.0 & 0.5 & 0.0\\
C & 0.0  & 43.0 & 0.0 & 3.6 & 10.8 & 6.7 & 1.1 & 3.2 & 0.4 & 31.1 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! you answer was very useful! cheers!!

Comment: @MartínTorresBrunengo, you are welcome! however, here is policy to express thankfulness by voting (by clicking on up-pen at the top left side of answer) of question (for what you need reputation at least 15 points) and the accept this answer which you the most like (by clicking check mark) :-).

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array, caption, float, booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\setcellgapes{5pt}
\makegapedcells

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H] %
  \centering \caption{atomic composition of the different points analyzed by the DES probe} \label{DES probe}

  \begin{tabular}{c *{13}S[table-format=2.1] } %
    \toprule
                     & \multicolumn{13}{c}{\bfseries{Weight \%}} \\ %
    \cmidrule(lr){2-14}
    {\textbf{Point}} & {\textbf{C}} & {\textbf{O}} & {\textbf{Mg}} & {\textbf{Al}} & {\textbf{Si}} & {\textbf{S}} & {\textbf{K}} & {\textbf{Ca}} & {\textbf{Ti}} & {\textbf{Fe}} & {\textbf{Zn}} & {\textbf{Cu}} & {\textbf{Pd}} \\%
    \midrule
    A & 0.0 & 50.5 & 1.6 & 7.4 & 24.3 & 7.9 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 6.2 & 0.6 & 0.0 & 1.5 \\
    B & 32.1 & 46.2 & 0.2 & 1.9 & 5.9 & 1.9 & 0.7 & 0.7 & 0.3 & 9.6 & 0.0 & 0.5 & 0.0 \\
    C & 0.0 & 43.0 & 0.0 & 3.6 & 10.8 & 6.7 & 1.1 & 3.2 & 0.4 & 31.1 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! you answer was very useful! cheers!!