# Can't compile a table due to a "Misplaced \omit" error message

Tags: tables

I am writing a table in LaTeX and when I compile an error message is displayed:

> `Error Misplaced \omit. \end{tabular}}.`

Could anyone help me to fix it?

```
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \caption{TGA/DTGA reaction intervals, peak temperatures and mass losses of oil shale combustion}
    \resizebox{15cm}{2cm}{
    \begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c}
        \toprule
        &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Second stages} \multicolumn{5}{c}{Third stages}\\
        \cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){2-4} \cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){5-7}
        \bfseries{$\beta$($^o$C min$^{-1}$)}&\bfseries{Interval($^o$C)}& \bfseries{T$_{max}$$^a$($^o$C)}&\bfseries{loss(\%)}&\bfseries{Interval($^o$C)}&\bfseries{T$_{max}$($^o$C)}&\bfseries{loss(\%)}\\
        \midrule
        5& 230$-$533 & 387 & 15.2 & 533$-$924 & 593 and 679 & 7.5 \\
        10& 250$-$546 & 402 & 15.0 & 546$-$944 & 612 and 693 & 7.4 \\
        20& 255$-$567 & 414  & 15.4 & 567$-$940 & 629 and 710 & 7.2  \\
        30& 262$-$571 & 423 & 15.3 & 571$-$949  & 639 and 721 & 6.9 \\
        40& 274$-$572 & 437 and 453 & 15.5 & 572$-$942 & 649 and 732 & 6.8 \\
        50& 273$-$576 & 451 & 15.6 & 576$-$948 & 649 and 741& 6.7 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}}\\\smallskip
    \parbox{0.85\textwidth}{\scriptsize{$^a$The temperature at which the maximum mass loss rate reached}}
    \label{TGAtable}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Use the `&` between the `\multicolumn`, not before.

Comment: Btw: `\bfseries` has no argument.

Comment: also don't use `\\ ` before vertical skips and if you can avoid it at all, avoid scaling the table (never use both scale arguments as that scales it by different amounts in each direction, completely destroying the font)

Comment: Please see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/400154/distribute-columns-evenly#comment996026_400154 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/400036/multicolumn-alignment#comment995684_400036 and https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `\multicolumn` statements contain several errors; I hope I managed to fix them in the code shown below.

Do give more thought to organizing the header material. E.g., instead of showing both variables and their units on one and the same line, split the information across two lines. This'll make it much easier on your readers to figure out the structure of the table. To typeset en-dashes, use `--`, not `$-$` (math-minus symbol). Don't overuse **bold-facing**. For sure, don't even think about using bold-facing as a substitute for organizing the tabular material in a clear and crisp way. I would also like to recommend that you familiarize yourself with the `threeparttable` package, which is very useful for typesetting table-related footnotes and placing various markers in the body of the `tabular` environment.

Observe that the code below gets by without a call to `\resizebox`, and that it doesn't resort to bold-facing at all. Just for completeness, I'm also showing the table as produced by your code, fixed up minimally to make it compilable without errors.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable} % for \tnote macro and \tablenotes env.
\renewcommand{\TPTtagStyle}{\textit}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht!]
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{TGA/DTGA reaction intervals, peak temperatures and mass losses of oil shale combustion}
\label{TGAtable}

\begin{tabular}{@{} S[table-format=2.0] *{6}{c} @{}}
    \toprule
    &\multicolumn{3}{c}{Second stages} 
    &\multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{Third stages}\\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-7}
    {$\beta$}
    & Interval & $T_{\max}$\tnote{a} & loss
    & Interval & $T_{\max}$\tnote{a} & loss\\
    {(\si{\celsius\per\minute})}
    & (\si{\celsius}) & (\si{\celsius}) & (\%)
    & (\si{\celsius}) & (\si{\celsius}) & (\%)\\
    \midrule
     5& 230--533 & 387 & 15.2 & 533--924 & 593 \& 679 & 7.5 \\
    10& 250--546 & 402 & 15.0 & 546--944 & 612 \& 693 & 7.4 \\
    20& 255--567 & 414 & 15.4 & 567--940 & 629 \& 710 & 7.2  \\
    30& 262--571 & 423 & 15.3 & 571--949 & 639 \& 721 & 6.9 \\
    40& 274--572 & 437 \& 453 & 15.5 & 572--942 & 649 \& 732 & 6.8 \\
    50& 273--576 & 451 & 15.6 & 576--948 & 649 \& 741 & 6.7 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\footnotesize
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[a] The temperature at which the maximum mass loss rate is reached.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello, sorry i can't install the \usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}. The program said that the package was not found.

Comment: @MartínTorresBrunengo - The package to install is called `threeparttable`, not `\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}`. If your TeX distribution cannot locate the `threeparttable` package, I'm afraid there's something very odd about the installation of your TeX distribution. Which TeX distribution do you have?

Comment: I have the TeXstudio. Regrettably the program don't install the package, the program display the following message: File `threeparttable.sty' not found. Would you mind telling me a possible solution?

Comment: @MartínTorresBrunengo - TeXstudio is a "front end", it is *not* a TeX distribution. Examples of TeX distributions are TeXLive and MiKTeX.

Comment: Yes! sorry, i am using MiKTex.

Comment: @MartínTorresBrunengo - If the `mpm` ("MiKTeX package manager") utility can't locate and install the `threeparttable` package, there's something seriously wrong with your MiKTeX installation. Not having access to your computer (obviously!), I am unable to offer a further diagnosis. Incidentally, the use of the `threeparttable` environment in my solution is nice, but it's not absolutely essential.

Comment: Ok Mico, in spite of the fact that I can't fix the problem of the treeparttable, your suggestions to improve the table were very useful !  Have a good new year night! Cheers!

Comment: @MartínTorresBrunengo - Have a good new year as well! It occurred to me that I should maybe have mentioned that `mpm` needs to be run *twice*, with both user and admin rights, while adding the `threeparttable` package. Only then can one be sure that a newly-added package will be fully accessible. Alternatively, perform a full re-install of all of MiKTeX, with the "full" version that downloads and installs all packages right away.